# Designing an 'electronic dice' with counter 74HC163

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying to design an 'electronic dice' using counter `74HC163`. 
I want it to count from 1 to 6 and then to reset. 
I observed the 16 states first and then tried to make the counter cycle through a shorter number of states. So the reset (pin 2) was connected to the last output (pin 11). I got 6 states (8-15)!

Comment: Yes - show what you've done so far and get someone to comment.

Comment: You should edit your question to provide new information rather than adding comments.

Comment: I am new here David :)

Answer (score 2):

The 74x163 is a 4-bit synchronous counter.  I notice it has a clear input, so you can detect the count being 5 (you'll be counting 0-5 instead of 1-6) and assert clear.  Check the timing diagram carefully to make sure that doesn't cause a race condition.  It may be OK since the term "synchronous" implies things only happen on the edge of clock, but you want to make sure that detecting 5 and then asserting clear doesn't immediately reset the counter.  If so, you may need to detect 6 instead, or some other trick to effectively make the clear input synchronous.

Of course this could all be done with a simpler circuit that uses a small microcontroller.  That can perform the 1-6 counting directly, debounce a user input, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The 74HC163 with its sychronous clear input should be perfect for this application.

Make sure you have a bypass capacitor (100nF - 1uF ceramic) directly across the power supply pins of the chip and make sure that every single unused input to the chip is tied to the appropriate logic level, either directly or through a resistor of a few K ohms.

Using Q3 connected to /MR is **not** what you want. It will never count if it starts at 0, and if it starts at 0x8 or higher it will count 8..F then stop forever. Instead, think about logic (gate or gates) that would bring /MR low (active) during the final valid state (0x5) so the output after the next rising clock edge will be 0.

If you choose to use partial decoding (for example by ignoring Q3) think about what that means if the counter starts up with a count of 0x8, say.